# Angular 5 store http data in local storage

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I want to minimize the number of network request from my application for that purpose I thought of storing data from GET APIs into the browser's local Storage. I thought of doing it in service so that whenever there is a request for the GET API the application first checks for the local storage if the data does not exists then only it makes the network request. I am here confused how do I store the data in the local storage i.e how to save the data from network request and then send the data to the subscriber. I know about .pipe() method but don't know the rxjs operator to use to save the data.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple - and yes you should use `pipe` for that

```
return http.get("something").pipe(
   tap(value=>save your value in local storage)
)
```

`tap` has the same signature (arguments) as `subscribe` and it is used to have peek on the value in pipe - you can say it behaves like subscription but without actual subsribing.

Comment: This will save the value in localStorage, but will also make a network call every time? I guess OP want to return data stored in localStorage if it exists.

Comment: but IF it out before http call

Comment: tap will get the value only if you subscribe, so this won't work.

Comment: @wFitz And tell me please, why would you do anything if there is no data request (subscription) huh?

Comment: @wFitz request wont be made neither without subscription, so what is your point here ?

Comment: @Antoniossss Thanks tap is the operator I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I am working in an implementation similar to your requirements.

Now, after login, I get all data that is not common to change, like auxiliary tables, and save them to localstorage. You don't need to do this, you can have them in memory, I do it because I also save the token, that has a validity of 1 hour. If you close the browser and reopen, I check if the token exists and is valid, if it is, I skip login. In that case, I read all the auxiliary tables data from localstorage.

So after login I call InitCache method of service.

```
InitCache() {
  this.http.get<IEmpresa[]>(
     this.url() + 'empresas',
     { headers: this.getAuthHeaders() }
  ).subscribe(
     data => {
        this.cache.Empresas = data;
        this.SaveToLocalStorage("Empresas"); // This is only needed if you skip login
     } 
  )
...other gets
}
```

Then I have a method in the service, that I call when I need that data.

```
Empresas() {
   return this.cache.Empresas;
}
```

This is working OK, but I don't like it because you need to logout/login to refresh data, or worse, click a button, ajjjjj.

New in progress solution : as I use asp.net core as a backend, I implemented signalR. I'll try to explain what it does.

When angular app starts, it connects to signalR hub, and waits for messages. In every controller of the endpoint, when I modify a auxiliary table, I send a message to clients, informing that "this" table changed, please update your cache.

The angular app receives this messages, makes the get call, updates its cache and saves to localstorage. And... the most important, the method in the service is now a BehaviourSubject,that means that when an update is received, it is dispatched to all subscribers ( I subscribe to this data in the components ).

I hope I managed to put in words this idea.